# How to get last one month's data from a table based on current month and year?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am facing some problem with the hive code. 
My `FROM TABLE` is partitioned based on month, year and day. I came up with the following code to get the data I need. The logic is something like if the current `mth` is `01` then change the `month` to 12 and the year to `yr - 1`
else change month to `mth - 1` and keep the year as is.

```
set hivevar:yr=2019;
set hivevar:mth=03;
set hivevar:dy=29;

SELECT * from 
FROM table
WHERE 
month = case when cast('${mth}' as int) = 01 then 12 else cast((cast('${mth}' as int) - 1) as string) end
AND year = case when cast('${mth}' as int) = 01 then cast((cast('${yr}' as int) - 1) as string) else '${yr}' end;
```

It is not working, my `select *` is coming empty. Please help.

`desc table`
[image: table]

Comment: can you describe in *english* what you are trying to get from the table given a date?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I want to get the last month's data based on the current month and year. e.g. if month is 03(2019) i want data from 02(2019). If the current month is 01(2019) then I want data from 12(2018).

Comment: is there a date column in the table or is it only month,year and date as separate columns?

Comment: Can you provide your table structure? If you change '${mth}' for, let's say, 05, and '${yr}' for 2019, does you query works?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala no. It is partitioned based on the month, year and day.

Comment: i get that..but as @AntonioVenerosoContreras asks..can you add the table structure to the question? sample data would also be helpful

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras I can't share the entire structure but its like I shared in the picture attached.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala please check the attached picture. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, you are trying to get data from the previous month given a date. If so, you can use inbuilt date functions to do it.

```
select *
from table 
where concat_ws('-',year,month,day) >= add_months(date_add(concat_ws('-','${yr}','${mth}','${dy}'),1-'${dy}'), -1) 
and concat_ws('-',year,month,day) < date_add(concat_ws('-','${yr}','${mth}','${dy}'),1-'${dy}')
```

*The solution assumes year, month and day are of the format yyyy, MM and dd. If not, adjust them as needed*

Also, you should consider storing `date` as a column even though you have it partitioned by year,month and day.

Comment: Using partitions can help the query to run faster, that is the reason I was not inclined to use in-built functions. And I can't DDL the prod tables. :'(
I was trying to figure out something else to do the same.

Comment: I know.. that’s why i said in addition to the partitioned columns